# Django+Graphene Error on Unknown argument while writing mutation

Tags: django, graphql

I am getting this as an error:

My mutations.py code looks like this:

```py
import graphene
from .types import ApplicationType

from api.graphql.helpers.save_application_helper import save_application_helper

class ApplicationMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        firstname = graphene.String()
        lastname = graphene.String()
        gender = graphene.String()
        district = graphene.String()
        pin_code = graphene.String()
        connection_type =graphene.String()
        category =graphene.String()
        govt_id_type =graphene.String()
        govt_id_number = graphene.String()
        load_applied = graphene.Int()

    application = graphene.Field(ApplicationType)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(self, info, requested_data):
        application  = save_application_helper(requested_data)
        return ApplicationMutation(
            application = application 
        )
```

I tried looking at the code but I cannot find any leads on why it is behaving like this.

Comment: Could you share the error message you're getting?